# RegEx only one dot inside string not at beginning or end

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a **regular expression** in **javascript** that only allows users to write this:

`abc.def`, `abc-def` or `abc`

So basically match a pattern that only contains letters *(only lowercase [a-z])* and a `.` or `-`. But does not match `-` or `.` at the beginning or end of string or multiple times(only one `.` or `-` per string)

So **not** allowing them to do:

`.....` `abc...abc` `abc.abc....` `abc----....` `...abc.abc` `.abc` `-abc` etc.

Comment: Are dot or hyphen allowed as the first character of the string?

Comment: I forgot to add that. No, a dot or hyphen is not allowed at the beginning of the string.

Comment: May be this - `/^[a-z]+(?:[-.]?[a-z]+)?$/` - is what you're looking for? ) Single dash or dot in ALL the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Regex would be:* `/^[a-z]+([\.\-]?[a-z]+)?$/`

*JavaScript:*

```
var text = 'abc.def';
var pattern = /^[a-z]+([\.\-]?[a-z]+)?$/;
if (text.match(pattern)) {
  print("YES!");
} else {
  print("NO!");
}
```

*See and test the code [here](http://ideone.com/DAvfF).*